# Redirect time command and stdout output into the same file via shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have following main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello Geek\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote some script to compile and run it

```
g++ -o test -g main.cpp
{ time ./test ; } 2>&1> /home/kj/bashTest/log
```

in the log I can see "Hello Geek" but the time output is displayed on console instead of log file.
I am not sure how to fix it even though there is some similar post regarding this.
Can anyone kindly provide me some advice?

Comment: `> /home/kj/bashTest/log 2>&1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to inverse two redirections :

```
{ time ./test ; } > /home/kj/bashTest/log 2>&1
```

If you redirect standard error first, it stays on console, equivalent to having no effect.

Comment: This is a nice answer explaining the importance of order: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37662/232207

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to redirect all streams into log:

```
{ time ./test ; } &> /home/kj/bashTest/log
```

This is generally my go-to if no stream splitting is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This solves my question as well:

```
g++ -o test -g main.cpp
{ time ./test ; } 2>&1 | cat > /home/kj/bashTest/log
```

Comment: Note this solution invokes a whole additional process, and as such, may be costly for large output streams.